# Java Applet network URL connection username and password visible in Java Console

Tags: java, applet, security

I have an applet that makes a connection to a protected URL for example:
URL = http://user:password@x.y.z/Name/Page.jsp

When I enable the JAVA Console and set the trace level to "5" I can see that a network connection is made and the username and password is revealed.

How do prevent the console to print the URL or protect my use

Answer (score 1):

Don't put sensitive data into Jars.  If you do, the motivated end user can hack it, with or without the console.

Comment: I do not store the data in the JAR, it is parameter to the jar. the applet tag parameters are built dynamically by querying a database. Still not sure how to protect this, except to encrypt and decrypt the url parameter within the jar applet. Looking for a shorter path...

Comment: Ecrypting and Decrypting the url parameter I guess will be useless, because the stack trace will still reveal the username and password for the URL.